# PFQueryTableView Controller not loading custom Cells

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

Im working on an app and I would like it to populate the cells based on users who are within a set distance from the currentuser. For some reason the customcells are not being populated with the correct objects. The labels and images that are supposed to be retrieved are blank. All i get is a blank cell. I made sure i gave the cell identifier the correct name, and i also made sure to link the tableviewcontroller and the tablecellview to their respective classes,but still no luck.

first i created initializers:

```
class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {



let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var currLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)

}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.parseClassName = "User"
    self.textKey = "FBName"
   // self.imageKey = "pictureURL"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.objectsPerPage = 10
    self.paginationEnabled = true

}
```

Then in viewDidLoad i enabled location services:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        loadData()
        println("location services enabled bruh")
    }
}
```

Next i overrode the queryfortable function:

```
 override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "User")
    if let queryLoc = currLocation {
        query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: PFGeoPoint(latitude: queryLoc.latitude, longitude: queryLoc.longitude), withinMiles: 50)
        query.limit = 40
        query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
        println("\(queryLoc.latitude)")
        return query

    } else {
        query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: PFGeoPoint(latitude: 37.411822, longitude: -121.941125), withinMiles: 50)
        query.limit = 40
        query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
        println("else statement")
        return query

    }
}
```

then the objectAtIndexPath function

```
 override func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> PFObject! {
    var obj : PFObject? = nil
    if indexPath.row < self.objects.count {
        obj = self.objects[indexPath.row] as? PFObject
    }
    return obj

}
```

and lastly I returned the cell, but for some reason it does not work:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell
    cell.userName?.text = object?.valueForKey("FBName") as? String
   let userProfilePhotoURLString = object?.valueForKey("pictureURL") as? String
    var pictureURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: userProfilePhotoURLString!)!
    var urlRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: pictureURL)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (NSURLResponse response, NSData data,NSError error) -> Void in
        if error == nil && data != nil {
            cell.userImage?.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
    cell.ratingsView?.show(rating: 4.0, text: nil)

    return cell
}
```

ps, i have the number of sections set to 1, just didnt think that method would be useful to show here.

Comment: i tried to check if it cell.userName was nil using println() from within cellforrowatindexpath, but it appears that method is not being called for some reason....

Comment: the object is a dictionary. When i try to retrieve the value using the key within println, the println function is not called, and since its located withing cellforrowatindex path we can assume that function isnt being called either

Comment: can you show your `tableview numberOfRowsInSection` function? are you calling `objectAtIndexPath` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to get data of each row? Did u try calling tableView.reloadData() after downloading your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I found the issue! The issue was that I was trying to use `PFQuery` in order to retrieve a list of `PFUser`s. I found out that cannot be done using `PFQuery` infact `PFUser` has it's own query method for retrieving information from its users.

all i had to do was replace this line:
`let query = PFQuery(className: "User")` 
with this:
`let query = PFUser.query()`